# Next book/learning tool

Tags: classical-latin, declension, resource-request

What would you suggest as a next step for books or learning tools for Classical Latin? In the last 4 years I've completed Duolingo Latin, read Lingua Latina and Cambridge Latin a few times along with some other beginner texts I found at used bookstores, followed many Latin creators  online for podcasts, videos, classes, etc. I've got the StoryBookLearning program and my journal for the last couple of years is written in Latin (in old Roman cursive for funsies.) I feel almost like I've hit a wall with declensions that aren't first or second and a lot of the popular Latin texts are still way too advanced for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're struggling with declensions and real-world texts really are *way* too difficult I'd honestly suggest doing Cambridge Latin again.

Comment: I suggest spending time on drilling the declensions and conjugations into your head. With the amount of texts you've read and the difficulty you describe, I think focusing on grammar and inflections a more productive way to go than trying more texts. You can have texts on the side, but not only texts.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Agreed, and diligently going through it as well. Is also recommend dropping Duolingo, Lingua Latina, and other distractions. By the end of any introductory series you should know all the basic morphology.

Comment: I agree with the others you may want to revisit Cambridge Latin. When you say you completed Lingua Latina, did you complete both books? _Roma Aeterna_ is more advanced and will help prepare you for real works.

Comment: Also, are you simply reading these or doing all the exercises? It makes a huge difference to do those in addition to just reading.

Comment: I do feel like declensions are my main issue, I have not made an attempt to memorize any, I got first and second down thanks to HiPaws songs getting stuck in my head.

Comment: I did not do Roma Aeterna, I can try that one next and do Cambridge again. Thanks everyone.